# Conditional SUM on oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, conditional-statements

I have the data in the follow way:

```
ITEM  LOCATION  UNIT RETAIL  QUANTITY 
100     KS         10          -10
200     KS         20           30
```

I want the sum of positive quantities (quantity > 0) and sum of negative quantities (quantity < 0).

How do I get those column sum based on condition?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `SUM(CASE  ... )`:

```
SELECT item, location,
   SUM(CASE WHEN quantity > 0 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS positive_sum,
   SUM(CASE WHEN quantity < 0 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS negative_sum
FROM your_table
GROUP BY item, location;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377811)**</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` in conjunction with the `SUM` function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb573/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ITEM, LOCATION, QUANTITY ) AS
          SELECT 100, 'KS', -10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100, 'KS', -10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100, 'KS', -20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100, 'KS',  10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100, 'KS',   5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 200, 'KS',  10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 200, 'KS',  20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 200, 'KS',   5 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT item,
       location,
       SUM( GREATEST( quantity, 0 ) ) AS positive_quantities,
       SUM( LEAST( quantity, 0 ) )    AS negative_quantities
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY item, location
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb573/1/0)**:

```
| ITEM | LOCATION | POSITIVE_QUANTITIES | NEGATIVE_QUANTITIES |
|------|----------|---------------------|---------------------|
|  100 |       KS |                  15 |                 -40 |
|  200 |       KS |                  35 |                   0 |
```

Comment: I like the idea of hiding `CASE` with `GREATEST/LEAST` :) Could you compare execution plans with my solution?

Comment: @lad2025 Unsurprisingly - they both have identical plans. If you wish to profile them you can see if they have different performance (but I doubt it as they do exactly the same thing). Ultimately it comes down to which is more readable/maintainable/easier to type/etc...