# Select sum of 2 different types

Tags: oracle

How to write select query to get sum(credit) and sum(debit) and difference from 2 columns like below. Where transaction type 0 is credit and transaction type 1 is debit.

[table records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OgpI.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: I agree with @Aleksej, we need more detail. But as a shot in the dark, maybe take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234844/conditional-sum-on-oracle-sql) about conditionally summing using `CASE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the sum of values only when the type is 0 (and ignoring the other values from the same column), you use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum ( case transaction_type_id when 0 then amount end ) as credit, ....
```

You can do the same for `debit`, and take the difference for, well, the difference.

```
select sum ( case transaction_type_id when 0 then amount end )      as credit,
       sum ( case transaction_type_id when 1 then amount end )      as debit,
       sum ( case transaction_type_id when 0 then amount end ) 
         -  sum ( case transaction_type_id when 1 then amount end ) as difference
from   your_table
;
```

With some luck, the optimizer will see that each sum is calculated twice, and it will actually compute each only one time and use the result in both places. Otherwise the `difference` could be written more tightly with a single conditional sum, but it would be different from the first two.